# Remove proximity alert inside broadcast receiver android

Tags: android, geofencing, proximitysensor

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am using proximity alert. So Everything is working fine. Now What I want to do as soon as enter event triggered I want to remove that alert. How to do that? may I do it in broadcast receiver or some where else?
My code looks like.

```
// in abc class
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        locationManager.addProximityAlert(
                latitude, 
                longitude, 
                POINT_RADIUS, 
                PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION,
                proximityIntent                );

// this is broadcast receiver 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) 
        {
            // here I want to stop this alert... ANy solution how to stop this          
            }
        else
        {
        } 
 }
```

how to do that? Need help. thank you.

Comment: is it like you want to display an Alert and dismiss it after 1-2 seconds ?

Comment: no not like that. what I am doing i am using expiration time as -1 which causes continuous gps usage. so that's why i want to remove that alert so it reduce battery consumption. Once user know's that he enter into that location then no need to track it right? So i just want to remove that alert .

Answer (score 0):

Use LocationManager. removeProximityAlert(PendingIntent).  Just pass it in the intent that you passed into addProximityAlert.  If you don't have that saved right now, you'll have to save it to a variable in your Activity/Service.

Comment: thank you for reply.So have to save that my pending intent. I tried your solution and removing my alert. But I tried it into my activity. My problem is that how can i inform my activity that entered event is triggered; so for that reason i tried to remove it inside broadcast receiver. Two things if i tried to remove alert inside receiver then i need pending intent with me and second thing is if try it in activity then i need when entered event is triggered. So how can i active this .. any solution

Answer (score 0):

in my experience the Pending intent has a different flag:

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent
                                            .getBroadcast(
                                                    NotificationService.this,
                                                    0,
                                                    intent,
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and when the notify gets seen, discarded or used  i got this code:

```
((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                    .cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

where notification id will be 0 in your code.
First option is to stop the alert, second is to dismiss it from the notification menu.